# Handling InterruptedException in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point, interrupted-exception

I'm wondering what's the correct way of handling `InterruptedException` in `main` thread. When the `main` thread gets interrupted?

I see that `join()` method throws `InterruptedException`, but I'm wondering how can I clean up the secondary thread to terminate gracefully.

Here's the sample program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("[thread] exiting...");
            }
        };

        System.out.println("[main] starting the thread");
        t.start();
        System.out.println("[main] interrupting the secondary thread");
        t.interrupt();

        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("[main] exiting");
    }
}
```

This code will print the following output:

```
[main] starting the thread
[main] interrupting the secondary thread
[thread] exiting...
[main] exiting
```

I found that certain articles on the internet (such as this http://www.yegor256.com/2015/10/20/interrupted-exception.html) suggest to set `interrupt` flag to true and to throw `RuntimeException`. I don't see how this would mitigate the situation (cleaning the remaining threads before exiting).

Thanks.

Edit: code snipped I referred in a comment

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("[thread] interrupting the main thread...");
                mainThread.interrupt();
                System.out.println("[thread] exiting...");
            }
        };

        System.out.println("[main] starting the thread");
        t.start();
        System.out.println("[main] interrupting the secondary thread");
        t.interrupt();

        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("[main] InterruptedException indeed happened");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw e;
        }
        System.out.println("[main] exiting");
    }
}
```

Comment: you wrap your Thread in Task and use stateProperty().addListener of that Task

Comment: As long as your Thread t is not marked as a daemon, it should be terminated together with the main program.

Comment: @kamel2005 Could you explain what do you mean? What I want to achieve is that the main thread would stop the long-running secondary thread and handle properly external interruptions/signals.

Answer (score 3):

In your example nothing is going to interrupt the main thread, none of the code handling the `InterruptedException` thrown from the call joining on the secondary thread will get executed. So it really doesn't matter. The point of setting the interrupt flag is to let other things executing in that thread know of the interruption so everything can quit what it's doing, that is not a concern here.

You could wrap the main method in a `try-catch` block that logs anything it catches. That's a normal thing to do to make sure all exceptions get logged.

Your code invokes `interrupt` on the secondary thread. As long as that thread is written to respond to interruption by cleaning up and quitting then there isn't any more to do.

Don't use `Thread.interrupted()`, use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`. The `interrupted` method clears the interrupt flag as a side effect.

Catching the `InterruptedException` and throwing a `RuntimeException` is not consistent with how the `java.util.concurrent` classes are written. It's more idiomatic to let the `InterruptedException` be thrown than to wrap it in an unchecked exception.

The example code can't be interrupted by signals, you would have to implement that functionality yourself by writing your own signal handler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My concern was that the main thread could somehow get interrupted from an external program (for instance SIGINT, but it's not the case) or OS kernel.
I managed to interrupt main thread from secondary thread before terminating (see added snipped at the end of the question). 
So, as far as I understand, that exception cannot be thrown if no secondary thread will interrupt main thread?

Comment: @Predkambrij: you can choose to write code that handles signals and interrupts threads in response. Otherwise there's no connection. The exception gets thrown only if something calls interrupt on the thread.